# How should I determine what seed to use while using "flexclust" package?

Tags: r, clustering

I am trying to find a clustering solution with the help of `flexclust` package in R. The following code has been adapted from the vignette for the `flexclust` package:

```
library(flexclust)
library(ISLR)

Auto <- read.table(Auto)
AutoMinus <- Auto[ -c(8:9)]
AutoMinus.mat <- as.matrix(AutoMinus)

# Setting the parameters

fc_cont <- new("flexclustControl")  
fc_cont@tolerance <- 0.01   
fc_cont@iter.max <- 25
fc_cont@verbose <- 1
fc_family <- "kmeans"             

seed1 <- 12345
fc_seed <- seed1
num_clusters <- 3
set.seed(fc_seed)

AutoMinus.cl <- kcca(AutoMinus.mat, k = num_clusters, save.data = TRUE, control = fc_cont, family = kccaFamily(fc_family))
summary(AutoMinus.cl)

cluster info:
  size  av_dist max_dist separation
1  122 263.0698 525.3528   480.3347
2  180 217.1523 610.9503   478.7658
3   90 290.9777 905.5731   551.2422
```

Every time I change the seed, the output changes. I am evaluating different outputs based on lowest `av_dist`, lowest `max_dist` and minimum `separation`. My understanding is `separation` is within a given cluster. I tried to find the definition of `separation` in the documentation, but couldn't find it. My questions are:

1. How do I set the seed that will give me the best/optimal(?) solution?
2. Are there any general good practices for initializing a seed value?
3. Is my understanding of `separation` correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you believe there is a relationship between the seed value and the goodness of the model or are you asking how many seeds to try?

Comment: I don't think that logically there would be relationship between a given seed value and goodness of clustering. However, if you read the vignette for the package on Github, the author makes a comment about choosing a given seed value. But doesn't further expound on the issue. My understanding is that setting seed only helps in producing reproducible results. But, in this case it seems to mean more.

Answer (score 2):

#### Don't optimize the seed

It's okay to loop over seeds 1 to 10 and use an (unsupervised!) internal measure to choose the "best".

But messing around with the seed to get the best result is **overfittting**. You cannot do this on real data.

#### If the seed is important, then the algorithm failed

If the results vary a lot, this shows they are **not stable, but random**. If the method doesn't reliably produce a good result, consider the results to be "not better than random".

Comment: Just FYI, I am doing clustering on actual data. I used the `Auto` dataset just for a reproducible example.

Comment: That presentation is not by the author of flexclust (which btw. is horribly slow). I do not really agree with that presentation, I doubt the "best" clustering result found is meaningful.

Comment: Sorry about the oversight! You are right about the author of the package. I will correct my previous comment. [Here](https://github.com/ds4ci/CustSegs/blob/master/vignettes/Cluster-Volunteers-Data-Set.Rmd) the Github link to an example of `flexcust` that alludes to importance of a seed value.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in saying that setting the seed is good for creating reproducible results. This is often useful for code debugging or for HW assignments where the teacher wants to make it easier to grade the assignment. However there is no way to 'optimally' set the seed. All setting the seed does is give the random number generator (RNG) a place to start. However the RNG is programmed to avoid 'non-random' output. By choosing a specific seed (or set of seeds) you can create bias in your results. My advice would be to let the random number generator do it's job.

In this case the random numbers are being accessed in  the kcca() function when it chooses an k initial starting center points for the k-means algorithm. By setting the seed you are essentially telling the k-means algorithm to use the same starting centers each times it runs. The k-means algorithm itself is not-guaranteed to converge to the global optimum so different starting points for the algorithm can lead to different results.